# sql to find only the empty log_id in log file

Tags: sql

Having a long file like this:

```
 log_id     user_id   timestamp
4534500     5fcd      1577848665     
67ooo33     6gh3      1577848677
            6gh3      1577848622
            5ffg      1577848665
            5ffg      1577849000
```

Is there a way to find only the user with empty log_id?
For example the above example could return the final result:

```
user_id 
5ffg
```

user 5ffg is the only one with only empty log_id

Could easily find all the records with empty log_id, how to find the only empty log_id?

Comment: what is the RDBMS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using not exists -

```
select distinct user_id from tablename t
where not exists 
         (select 1 from tablename t1 where t.user_id=t1.user_id and log_id is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fahmi's solution works, but if you have a very large table, NOT EXISTS (and NOT IN) may be perform sluggishly.  An alternative is to use LEFT JOIN:

```
select distinct t1.user_id 
  from MyTable t1
    left join MyTable t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                          and t2.log_id is not null
  where t1.log_id is null
    and t2.user_id is null
;
```